# Error in trying to redo the example of In-Flight Entertainment System M2DOC

Tags: m2doc

I want to use M2DOC instead of the HTML generation for sharing my Capella model.
I installed m2doc and I generate the word document of the SA layer by doing only "generate documentation" (right click on the "Template SA Complete.genconf" downloaded with m2doc) (see screenshot).
[Generate SA documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVcUO.png)

In this way, I have the SA_Complete.docx well generated.

I want to use this template on my project. Thus, firstly I try to recreate a "Template SA Complete.genconf" in the In-Flight Entertainment project :
-right click on the docx template, "Initialize Documentation Configurations"
-variable name : click on "In-Flight Entertainment System.capella"
[variable_name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W05ig.png)

- right click on (my) "Template SA Complete.genconf" > "Validate Documentation Template"
  And I have some errors...

The first one : '''Couldn't find the 'isRepresentationDescriptionName(EClassifier=Capability,java.lang.String)' service <--- The predicate never evaluates to a boolean type([Nothing(Couldn't find the 'isRepresentationDescriptionName(EClassifier=Capability, java.lang.String)'service)])'''

[error_msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZrwg.png)

I followed this procedure : https://www.m2doc.org/ref-doc/1.0.0/index.html#initializing-a-generation-configuration
I started from the "beginning" (without doing anything in the template) to check that I was starting on a good basis. but it's probably not the case... Why? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that the option SiriusSession is referencing the .aird file in your Capella project. You should use the relative path to the .aird file. Once the SiriusSession is properly deined, Sirius services will be available.
You can use existing .genconf files in the IFE example to see how the configuration is done.

Comment: I had actually also been inspired by the existing genconf file. However, my .genconf was in a (new) folder. Thus, even if I had written "In-Flight Entertainment System.aird" for the SiriusSession (like the existing genconf file), it was not the name of the file aird that it need but actually its relative path. Thank you. It's solved.